# Out-File doesn't write any output

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following problem:

The script doesn't write anything in my export.txt file, but it does say "File found!"...

```
$client = "my-workstation"
$file = "c$\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
$export = "C:\temp\export.txt"

If(Test-Path "\\$client\$file")
{
   write-host $client | Out-File $export
   write-host "File found!"
}
```

Comment: write-host doesn't return anything, so nothing is written to the file.

Comment: If you want to see the output on the console and write it in file you can use tee-object cmdlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Write-Host cmdlet writes messages to the *console*, it *doesn't* put anything to the *pipeline* thus you have to omit the `Write-Host`:

```
$client | Out-File $export
```

Comment: Oh, I see.. Thank you!